Memory Level Parallelism (MLP) measurement
I need to find the Memory Level Paralelism (MLP) or the number of memory request that are concurrently held by Miss Status Handling registers (MSHRs) / Fill buffers at each cache level during a program execution in C/C++.
I found a link which explains using different performance counter events to measure L1 and L2 MSHRs.
I am looking for a C/C++ code.

You can run a C++ program under perf stat  ./a.out with -e task-clock,cycles,instructions,l1d_pend_miss.pending or whatever other events you want to look at.  That event exists on Skylake, but I'm not sure exactly what it counts.  It sounds promising, but probably doesn't increment by the number of outstanding misses every cycle.
